# Validating AdminNo in Database

Tags: java, sql

I have a textbox that takes in the input and validates whether there is a record in the database. If there is no record, it should display a JOptionPane. However, if i input any random number that is not in the database and press the check button, nothing happens. If i input an adminNo which is in the DB, the check button will work. How do i solve it? I think its more of my logic in the codes which is the problem

```
JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
    btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    try{
                    String conn = "select instrument, period, adminNo from reservation "
                            + "where adminNo = '" + txtAdmin.getText() + "'"; 
                    PreparedStatement pst = sqliteConnection.dbConnector().prepareStatement(conn);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

                    while(rs.next()) {
                        String adminNo = rs.getString("adminNo");
                        if(txtAdmin.getText().equals(adminNo)){
                            System.out.println("Admin number from text: " + txtAdmin.getText() + "Admin number from DB: " + adminNo);
                        lblDisplayMusicalInstrument.setText(rs.getString("instrument"));
                        lblDisplayDuration.setText(rs.getString("period"));
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Admin not in database");
                }
                    }

                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }
    }

);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: I have a feeling its something to do with (+ "where adminNo = '" + txtAdmin.getText() + "'"; )

Comment: i don't think `while/else` is a valid block structure

Comment: so what if I put the following in the txtAdmin field =>  `1'; DELETE * FROM RESERVATION;`?  You don't have to answer -- just fix your code -- google search on SQL injection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code

```
JButton btnCheck = new JButton("Check");
btnCheck.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        int count = 0;
        try{
            String conn = "select instrument, period, adminNo from reservation "
                        + "where adminNo = '" + txtAdmin.getText() + "'"; 
            PreparedStatement pst = sqliteConnection.dbConnector().prepareStatement(conn);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                count++;
                String adminNo = rs.getString("adminNo");
                if(txtAdmin.getText().equals(adminNo)){
                    System.out.println("Admin number from text: " + txtAdmin.getText() + "Admin number from DB: " + adminNo);
                lblDisplayMusicalInstrument.setText(rs.getString("instrument"));
                lblDisplayDuration.setText(rs.getString("period"));
                }
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(count == 0) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Admin not in database");
        }

    }
});
```